# Autowire a parameterized constructor in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, constructor, parameter-passing

I am not able to autowire a bean while passing values in paramterized constructor.

How to call the parameterized constructor using SpringBoot?

```java
@Component
public class MainClass {

    public void someTask() {
        AnotherClass obj = new AnotherClass(1, 2);
    }

}
//Replace the new AnotherClass(1, 2) using Autowire?

@Component
public class AnotherClass {
    private int number,age;

    public AnotherClass(int number, int age) {
        super();
        this.number = number;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I want to autowire "AnotherClass" bean.
How to remove the `new AnotherClass(1, 2);`
How can I place `@Autowire` here?

Comment: Hi there, what do you want to do? is it too confusing what you try to do, first you need to know `auto-wiring`definition and if you really need to implement in this case. Please read a little this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection

Comment: Thanks @JonathanJohx for replying
Can you tell me how to call the parameterized constructor using SpringBoot?

Comment: First at all, a class added as  `@Component` that is injected in Spring container is an object that possible you can define its scopes if you want to have one by request/singleton but by default its scope is singleton, then this means if you put that annotation then you will have an object only, then you really want to have one `AnotherClass` as Component then you can define a `@Bean` in your config class creating a method on the annotation and putting `return new AnotherClas(number, age);`

Comment: @JonathanJohx One last query! How will I pass dynamic values to number and age in the configuration class?

Comment: as I mentioned before I need to know really what do you want, could we talk by email so that we can talk better, ok?

Answer (score 17):

You need to specify this bean in the constructor:

```java
@Component
public class MainClass {

    private final AnotherClass anotherClass;

    // this annotation is NOT required if there is only 1 constructor, shown for clarity.
    @Autowired
    MainClass(AnotherClass anotherClass) {
        this.anotherClass = anotherClass;
    }
    public void someTask() {
        // anotherClass is already instantiated by the time you get here.
    }

}
```

---

**Option 1:** Directly allow `AnotherClass` to be created with a component scan.

Now, in order for Spring to be able to construct `AnotherClass` as a bean, you need to tell it in a 'Spring way' about where it gets it's values from:

```java
@Component
public class AnotherClass {
    private final int number,age;

    // also not needed if this is the only constructor.
    @Autowired
    public AnotherClass(
// @Value is a spring annotation to provide spring the value it needs for this parameter.
                        @Value("${property.number:0}") int number, 
                        @Value("${property.age:0}") int age) {
        this.number = number;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

What this is doing, is pulling 2 properties, `property.number` and `property.age` from `application.properties`|`application.yml` for the value(s) of those integers.

You will need to ensure both of these classes are on the component scan path, or else spring boot won't attempt to make beans of these classes.

---

**Option 2:** Use a Configuration Class to make the `AnotherClass` bean

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationClass {

    @Bean
    public AnotherClass anotherClass {
        return new AnotherClass(1,2)
    }
}
```

In this example, you **would not** annotate `AnotherClass` with `@Component`.

---

**Option 3:** Use a custom factory method [as found in this blog](https://medium.com/@davebarda/creating-a-dynamically-initialized-bean-in-spring-18d6d41d24df#b0cc).

Again, with this strategy, ***do not*** annotate `AnotherClass` with `@Component`

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationClass {

    @Bean
    public BiFunction<Integer, Integer, MyPrototype> myPrototypeFactory() {
        return start, age -> anotherClass(start, age);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public AnotherClass anotherClass(Integer start, Integer age) {
        if (start == null || age == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("start was: " + start + ", age was: " + age + ". Neither can be null!");
        }
        return new AnotherClass(start,age);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
@Component
public class MainClass {

    private final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, AnotherClass> anotherClassFactory;

    // this annotation is NOT required if there is only 1 constructor, shown for clarity.
    @Autowired
    MainClass(BiFunction<Integer, Integer, AnotherClass> anotherClassFactory) {
        this.anotherClassFactory = anotherClassFactory;
    }
    public void someTask() {
        AnotherClass ac = anotherClassFactory.apply(1,2);
        // do something with your new AnotherClass
    }

}
```

---

**Option 4:** Use `ObjectProvider` (Since Spring 4.3) [as found in this blog post](https://medium.com/@davebarda/creating-a-dynamically-initialized-bean-in-spring-18d6d41d24df#457b).

Again, with this strategy, ***do not*** annotate `AnotherClass` with `@Component`

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public AnotherClass createAnotherClass(Integer start, Integer age) {
        return new AnotherClass(start, age);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
@Component
public class MainClass {

    private final ObjectProvider<AnotherClass> anotherClassProvider;

    // this annotation is NOT required if there is only 1 constructor, shown for clarity.
    @Autowired
    MainClass(ObjectProvider<AnotherClass> anotherClassProvider) {
        this.anotherClassProvider = anotherClassProvider;
    }
    public void someTask() {
        // may need to cast the result of '.getObject()'
        AnotherClass ac = anotherClassProvider.getObject(/*start*/ 1, /*age*/ 2);
        // do something with your new AnotherClass
    }

}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to pass the value through property file? Like I want to pass dynamic value through code.

Comment: @krishna - in that case Option 2 is a viable approach. The thing to remember is that by default, spring beans are _Singletons_, so if you simply annotated `AnotherClass` with `@Component`, you only get instance of that object.

Comment: For the option 2, how will I pass the dynamic values? Like here we have card coded 1,2. How can I pass dynamic values through code?

Comment: @krishna - I would caution you with this approach, as it's not really something Spring is intended for, but you might be able to use an object factory of sorts according to this blog: https://medium.com/@davebarda/creating-a-dynamically-initialized-bean-in-spring-18d6d41d24df I will create an option 3 in the answer to distill the essence of this blog post.

Comment: I also added option 4 using ObjectProvider, I am unsure if that one is type safe and may need a cast.

Comment: @krishna - did this solve your question, or do you need more clarification?

Comment: @Bwvolleyball Option 3 seems to require only 2 annotations and they are not parameterized.   This would be helpful in terms of conciseness and clarity. Also the Java seems plain and portable outside of Spring.  Are those statements accurate?  Would this be a  standard approach to this problem?

Comment: @JohnMeyer - that's correct. In Option 3, Spring is only ensuring that these 2 functions get called on start. If you had direct access to the `myPrototypeFactory()`, this would give you a handle to create instances of `AnotherClass` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

***Another Option:*** you can also use the **XML Configuration** to wire the beans:

```xml
<beans>
   <bean id="mainClass" class="MainClass">
      <constructor-arg ref="anotherClass" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="anotherClass" class="AnotherClass">
      <constructor-arg index="0" type="int" value="1"/>
      <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="2"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The `MainClass` class

```java
public class MainClass {

    private final AnotherClass anotherClass;

    // this annotation is NOT required if there is only 1 constructor, shown for clarity.
    
    MainClass(AnotherClass anotherClass) {
        this.anotherClass = anotherClass;
    }
    public void someTask() {
        // anotherClass is already instantiated by the time you get here.
    }

}
```

The `AnotherClass` class

```java
public class AnotherClass {
    private int number,age;

    public AnotherClass(int number, int age) {
        super();
        this.number = number;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```