# Autowire class with arguments in constructor fails

Tags: java, spring

I have the following class :

```
public class ProducerWrapper<K, V> {

    Producer<K, V> producer;
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor;

    @Autowired
    public ProducerWrapper(Properties p, int poolsize) {
        ......
        log.info("Created kafka producer");
    }
 ....
```

I try to inject it in a different service :

```
@Service
public class mainService{

    @Qualifier("ProducerX")
    @Autowired
    private ProducerWrapper<Long,CustomObject1> p1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ProducerY")
    private ProducerWrapper<Long,CustomObject2> p2;
```

And I created the following configuration :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("main_package..")

public class MyConf {

    @Bean(name = "ProducerX")
    public ProducerWrapper<Long, CustomObject1> createProducerWrapper() throws IOException {
      FileInputStream propertiesFile = new FileInputStream("producerx.properties");
      properties = new Properties();
      properties.load(propertiesFile);
      return new ProducerWrapper<>(properties,5);
    }

    @Bean(name = "ProducerY")
    public ProducerWrapper<Long, CustomObject2> createProducerWrapper() throws IOException {
      FileInputStream propertiesFile = new FileInputStream("producery.properties");
      properties = new Properties();
      properties.load(propertiesFile);
      return new ProducerWrapper<>(properties,5);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a different properties file for each producer. The error I'm getting is the following :

```
    Error creating bean with name 'ProducerWrapper' defined in file [..../ProducerWrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'int' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    Parameter 1 of constructor in com.xx.xx.ProducerWrapper required a bean of type 'int' that could not be found.
```

If I remove the autowired annotation on top of the constructor, I'm getting a different error that the default constructor can't be found by Spring.

In addition, in the logs I see the following message that indicates that everything in the constructor was run :

```
2020-06-24 12:14:49.331  INFO 30912 --- [           main] c.a.a.ProducerWrapper      : Created kafka producer
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is p2 also set as @Autowired? In your code here is not.

Comment: @PatrickSantana yes indeed, I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the following stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926579/autowire-a-parameterized-constructor-in-spring-boot)

Bottom line :

1. The constructor in the ProducerWrapper class shouldn't have any annotation :

```
    //None annotation above constructor
    public ProducerWrapper(Properties p, int poolsize) {
        ......
        log.info("Created kafka producer");
    }
```

2. Create a configuration class for the beans just like I pasted in my main comment.
   3.Remove the Service annoatipn from the ProducerWrapper

Comment: You shouldn't even have the `@Component` annotation as you are creating beans through a configuration using `@Bean`. The `@Component` might even lead to an additional bean being constructed (or an error during startup).

Comment: I was about to say this. You are already creating beans through java config.

Comment: do I need to keep both Autowire and Qualifier ontop of the wrapper in the service class ?

Answer (score 0):

You have this signature:

```java
 @Autowired
    public ProducerWrapper(Properties p, int poolsize) {
...
```

You have not provided the "poolsize" parameter to be autowired. i.e. there's no integer that exists in your config that can be autowired into this variable.

To resolve this: Create a PoolSize class that wraps an int value. Then create a PoolSize object in your config to be autowired.

It says in the error output:

```
...No qualifying bean of type 'int' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

Comment: So I cant autowire primitives ? need to wrap them or use the Integer object ?

Comment: You can autowire primitives but the moment you want to use more than 1 int, you'll run into problems. To avoid that, wrap the int in an object type... now your code reads better too.

Comment: IMO wrappers for simple parameters like this is not very good practice, unless there are lots of grouped values that logically fit together. `@Value("${my.pool.size}") int poolSize` would work just as well for this use case.

Comment: you're right, it would work, but what happens when you want to wire another int in?